# .Net Core Find Free Disk Space on Different OS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way to find free space on different OS (Mostly Linux & Windows) using C# ASP.NET Core.

I found a way (using DriveInfo) to get free space by passing the Drive Name as a parameter. This is working fine on Windows, but I want the same for Linux as well.

```
public static int CheckDiskSpace(string driveLetter)
{
    DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(driveLetter);

    var totalBytes = drive.TotalSize;
    var freeBytes = drive.AvailableFreeSpace;

    var freePercent = (int)((100 * freeBytes) / totalBytes);

    return freePercent;
}
```

Passing the Drive (C:/) as below:

```
var freespace = DriveDetails.CheckDiskSpace("C:/");
```

**Update: This also works for Linux.**

Comment: You are aware that your code, being run as part of an ASP.NET Core application, runs on the server and not on the client, right? So you will always get about the same information, which is the server's disk space

Comment: My question title was modified, I need to find free disk space of the application on different OS

Comment: @johnny5 That duplicate is not even close to what's being asked here. The OP wants the currently running application's path, not the source code's. The edit was not really appropriate

Comment: My mistake, but the current title is misleading this question is related to finding the path and not the disk space

Comment: @johnny5, finding the path is a part of the question, the main question is finding disk space.

Comment: Dot Net Dev, you said you’ve already found a way using the drive info,  doesn’t this question pertain more to obtaining the path?

Comment: @johnny5 I found a way in Windows. I want something which works for Windows, Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Net.Core under Linux you can just call

```
var freeBytes = new DriveInfo(path).AvailableFreeSpace;
```

where path is some relative or absolute folder name, and it automatically provides you with drive information about the partition that stores this path. Tested on Net.Core 2.2.

As a contrast, in Windows you either:

A) Need to provide the drive letter (which unfortunately cannot be derived directly from relative path, so you need to do some additional work, and cannot be computed for UNC path at all).

B) Need to use Windows API (this works also with UNC paths):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
    out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
    out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
    out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path, out var freeBytes, out var _, out var __);
```

There are also some other exceptional cases so in the end my usage looks like following:

```
#if DEBUG        
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
    out long lpFreeBytesAvailable,
    out long lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
    out long lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
#endif

public long? CheckDiskSpace()
{
    long? freeBytes = null;

    try     
    {
#if DEBUG //RuntimeInformation and OSPlatform seem to not exist while building for Linux platform
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            long freeBytesOut;
            //On some drives (for example, RAM drives, GetDiskFreeSpaceEx does not work
            if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(_path, out freeBytesOut, out var _, out var __))
                freeBytes = freeBytesOut;
        }
#endif

        if (freeBytes == null)
        {
            //DriveInfo works well on paths in Linux    //TODO: what about Mac?
            var drive = new DriveInfo(_path);
            freeBytes = drive.AvailableFreeSpace;
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        //ignore the exception
    }

    return freeBytes;
}
```

Comment: ```new DriveInfo(path)``` does not work, for relative folder paths, in newer dotnet versions on linux. Tested with .net5.

Comment: See Rahul's answer below for the path problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` if you are using .Net Core

(OR)

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```